# Keeping JavaScript clock and countdown timer in sync

Tags: javascript

Please bear with me, this is my first post on the site and I'm also fairly new to JavaScript. I'm trying to create a html page that displays both the current time as a digital clock, and then a timer that counts down from 5:00 minutes to 0:00 and then repeats. The timer starts the first time the digital clock reaches the beginning of a minute (so second reading is "00"), after the page loads, so that it starts counting down as the minutes on the digital clock go up.

The problem is that the clock occasionally suffers from delay and corrects itself, which puts the timer out of sync with it, and I'm struggling to correct the countdown.

This is what I currently have:

```
function timeClock() {
    var stamp = new Date();
    var time = stamp.toLocaleString('en-GB', { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric', hour12: true})
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = time;
}

function startClock() {
    timeClock(); // Start displaying the current time
    setInterval(timeClock, 1000); // Update the time every second
}

var timeInSecs;
var ticker;

function startTimer(secs) {
timeInSecs = parseInt(secs);
ticker = setInterval(tick, 1000);
}

function tick() {
    var secs = timeInSecs;
    if (secs > 0) {
        timeInSecs--; 
    }
    else {
        clearInterval(ticker);
        startTimer((5*60)-1); // 5 minutes in seconds, -1 to sync up with clock
    }

    var mins = Math.floor(secs/60);
    secs %= 60;
    var pretty = ( (mins < 10) ? "0" : "" ) + mins + ":" + ( (secs < 10) ? "0" : "" ) + secs;

    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = pretty;
}

let countdownStarted = false;

// Detect start of the minute and execute above function
function checkSeconds() {
    var clockElement = document.getElementById('time');
    var clockValue = clockElement.innerText;
  
    // Extract seconds from the clock display
    var timeValue = clockValue.split(' ')[0];
    var seconds = timeValue.split(':')[2];
  
    // Check if seconds are "00" to trigger countdown
    if (seconds === '00' && !countdownStarted) {
        countdownStarted = true;
        startTimer((5*60)-1);
    }
  }
  
  startClock();
  setInterval(checkSeconds, 1000);
```

I tried creating a "synchronizeCountdown()" function that would take the current value of seconds from each, add them together, and then if it didn't equal 60 it would adjust the seconds value of the countdown by the difference. This instead means that the countdown only ticks down occasionally, and the second value is never correct. That function looks like this:

```
function synchronizeCountdown(secs) {
    var currClock = document.getElementById('time').innerText;
    
    var clockSecondValue = currClock.split(' ')[0];
    var clockSeconds = +clockSecondValue.split(':')[2];

    var currCountdown = document.getElementById('countdown').innerText;
    var countdownSeconds = +currCountdown.split(':')[0];

    if (countdownSeconds + clockSeconds == 60) {
        return;
    }
    else if (countdownSeconds + clockSeconds > 60 ) {
        var timediff = 60 - countdownSeconds + clockSeconds;
        return secs -= timediff;
    } else if (countdownSeconds + clockSeconds < 60) {
        return secs += (clockSeconds - countdownSeconds);
    }
}
```

and the function is then called as part of my tick() function, which is otherwise unchanged from above.

```
    secs %= 60;
    secs = synchronizeCountdown(secs);
    var pretty = ( (mins < 10) ? "0" : "" ) + mins + ":" + ( (secs < 10) ? "0" : "" ) + secs;
```

I'm definitely doing something wrong and it's probably a rookie a mistake, but any assistance with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: I've re-read what your trying to do a few times now, and I'm still at a loss on what your trying to do.  You have something that shows the current time, ok I get that, but then `and a looping timer that counts down in 5 minute intervals,`,  counts down from what?.   Regardless, yes, using an Interval for timing won't work, you could use an interval to check at intervals what values should be instead.  eg. If I wanted to count the minutes to New Years, I would subtract current time from new years time in an interval, and not calculate the minutes and substract in an interval.

Comment: I've edited my post to clarify, and also realised that I made a mistake when writing it out that might make more sense? So apologies for that, @Keith. I didn't realise that it's caused by setInterval drifting, but it actually looks like it behaves as expected in Chrome. It's for an internal app that will used only Chrome so it's not much an issue now.

Comment: Yeah, that makes more sense, so basically your waiting for the clock to be at exactly a minute point, eg.  12:40:00, and not 12:40:14  and then start this 5 min time countdown, you could maybe calculate how long to wait for timer to start, use a setTimeout here, and then a setInterval once running.  Again calculate inside the interval, rather than incrementing a counter.  Btw. the timer drifting is not just specific to any browser..